# NameError in Spree::Products#show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

This code used to work on rails 3.2.13 and spree 2.0, now with rails 4.0 and spree 2.1 raises the following error.

```
Showing /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_frontend-2.1.1/app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:

undefined local variable or method `active_record' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation:0xb3187c8>
```

**Extracted source (around line #19):**

```
 <% Spree::PROPERTIES_LEFT.each do |show_type| %>
   <% unless @product_properties.hash_for(show_type).empty? %>
     <% for title in @product_properties.hash_for(show_type).keys %>

       <h6 class="product-section-title"><%= title %></h6>
```

Rails.root: `/home/anakin/SpreeTravelData/openjaf/spree_travel_demo`

The line 19 is:

```ruby
 <% unless @product_properties.hash_for(show_type).empty? %>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: What is @product_properties being set to? What exact version of rails are you using? It looks like there's [a commit related to this in rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d87966c1c4119dbfa0808d7bd477b59a6b5f232c) merged in between 4.0.0 and 4.0.1.rc4, so I'm guessing you're on 4.0.0... if you upgrade to 4.0.1, does the error still happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to clean up your environment and make a clean **bundle install** and **bundle update** when you work with rails offline, it gets tricky to get a hold on all the dependencies. I had this exact problem and that's the way to go. Sadly is go online or go crazy.